# Getting AttributeError every time

Tags: python

I encountered a problem in which when Im trying to do several things on python like importing spacy or creating a virtual environment I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'
```

I tried reinstalling python but it doesn't help (I have Python 3.8.2)

Here is the full stack trace (when trying to import spacy) if you're interested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/realProject/ttt.py", line 1, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\thinc\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ._registry import registry
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\thinc\_registry.py", line 1, in <module>
    import catalogue
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\catalogue.py", line 18, in <module>
    AVAILABLE_ENTRY_POINTS = importlib_metadata.entry_points()
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 542, in entry_points
    ordered = sorted(eps, key=by_group)
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 540, in <genexpr>
    dist.entry_points for dist in distributions())
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 240, in entry_points
    return EntryPoint._from_text(self.read_text('entry_points.txt'))
  File "C:\Users\sbhtk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\metadata.py", line 491, in read_text
    return self._path.joinpath(filename).read_text(encoding='utf-8')
AttributeError: 'WindowsPath' object has no attribute 'read_text'
```

Comment: You've already asked the same question: [Getting Attribute Error when trying to import spacy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61196198/getting-attribute-error-when-trying-to-import-spacy)

Comment: Yeah I thought there that it has to do with spacy but apparentky it doesn't

Comment: I deleted that anyways

Comment: A quick google search of that error message returns multiple results, did you take a look at those?

Comment: You've screwed up your Python. Uninstall and reinstall, and read the PyPI page for compatibility notes on any packages you install before you install them. This looks a lot like you installed a package you shouldn't, such as the PyPI version of `pathlib`.

Comment: I've reinstalled python already and that didn't help

Comment: @AMC I trued everything I found but couldn't get any results